# SQL IF statement within the WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to have an IF statement within my WHERE clause in a stored procedure that I have. Here is what i want to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM Issues
WHERE
Issues.ProjectId = @projectId
and (Issues.MilestoneName IN('Milestone1, Milestone2, Milestone3') 
OR Issue.MilestoneId IS NULL)

-- this works fine but i only want the OR to run if a condition is met like so

SELECT * FROM Issues
WHERE
Issues.ProjectId = @projectId
and (Issues.MilestoneName IN('Milestone1, Milestone2, Milestone3') 
IF @milestoneStringInput IN('NULL')
BEGIN
 OR Issue.MilestoneId IS NULL)
END
```

is it possible to achieve this at all?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like stored procedures are **highly** vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference your variable directly in the WHERE clause, as with

```
SELECT * 
FROM Issues
WHERE
    Issues.ProjectId = @projectId
    and 
      (
        Issues.MilestoneName IN ('Milestone1, Milestone2, Milestone3') 
        OR 
          (
            Issue.MilestoneId IS NULL AND 
            @milestoneStringInput = 'NULL'
          )
      )
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, think i was trying to over-think it (im new to this) thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could offer some help!  One more note - you should update your original post's tags as requested.  Keeping the site clean so that future searchers can find this answer is a major part of what the website is for! Plus, it can help you in the future: some of the most experienced posters on here will only respond to questions they feel show proper research and thorough explanations. [There are plenty of tips!](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) That might be why your original question ended up with a downvote: try adding in the tag and responding to the commenter as requested.

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not allow conditional logic, only conditional expressions ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)). However, your situation does not require a conditional expression, because the same logic can be expressed with Boolean logic:

```
SELECT * FROM Issues
WHERE
Issues.ProjectId = @projectId
and (Issues.MilestoneName IN('Milestone1, Milestone2, Milestone3') 
AND ((@milestoneStringInput != 'NULL') OR (Issue.MilestoneId IS NULL))
```

The logic of the conditional is expressed on the last line: when `@milestoneStringInput != 'NULL'`, the condition becomes `TRUE`; on the other hand, when `@milestoneStringInput` is `'NULL'`, the `Issue.MilestoneId IS NULL` would be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Your original query does exactly what you need it to. Remember SQL as a very literal language and will execute in the order you write your code. If `Issues.ProjectId = @projectId` is met, then it will move on to your AND statement. The only way `OR Issue.MilestoneId IS NULL` will be executed is if `Issues.MilestoneName IN('Milestone1, Milestone2, Milestone3')` is not met first. The OR statement is saying "Hey, execute one or the other, depending on what condition is met first".